# Receiving a compile error Compile error at line 11 column 12 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Human].work(Decimal)

Tags: apex

I'm starting to learn OO programming and I've been following the Introduction to Apex for Non-Developers video.

They have an example listed which does not compile when i try to execute anonymous in a dev org.  The code is

```
public class Human {
    public double work (Double hours){
        double check;
        check = hours * 8.00;
        return check;
    }
}

Double paycheck;
Human man1 = new Human();
paycheck = man1.work(40.00);
system.debug(paycheck);
```

However if i change the 40.00 to 40 it compiles fine.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since i declared a double for paycheck.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It falls because of an implicit type conversion. You would want to "cast" 40.00 to a Double.

```
Paycheck = man1.work((double)40.00);
```

It's odd though, as I would have thought that the default type for that kind of literal would be a Decimal.